# Can a macro be written that runs an excel add in?

Tags: excel, add-in, vba

I have an add in for excel that connects excel to our accounting system.
Currently we are manually going to the add in and running it that way. I would like it to run each time the worksheet is opened.

Here are some images of where the add in is located:
[image: The add in is located in the Data tab]

[image: Need to run the refresh all]

I am not sure where to start looking to see if this is possible and its beyond my coding capabilities.

Is it possible to do this?
Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: I would start by using the [Macro Recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b)

Comment: is the addin locked? or do you have access to its codes?

Comment: If it was a straight-forward add-in, you could just call the Subs once you'd worked out their names (there are methods to do that) but in this case it's a VSTO add-in, so tricky to poke 'under the hood'. Your best bet is to ask the developer if it's possible to call specific routines using vba and if so how to do it.

Comment: Using the Macro Recorder I only get:    `Sub RefreshCostcon()
'
' RefreshCostcon Macro
'

'
End Sub`     I have no idea as to how to access the Add-in's code. I think I will see if the developer can help me. Many thanks for your tips and advice. Most appreciated. I will update this with how I get on with the developer for others who may have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same for all Add-ins but this is what I have done to get the Add-in I want to run when i open the workbook.

On the settings tab that is required for the Add-in there is a column that is called Refresh Interval. Originally I had this as 'onDemand'. By changing this to 'onLaunch' it now runs whenever I open the workbook.